# Qt Slot is not called when it lives on a thread created via std::async

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I wanted to create a Qt widget which communicates with other classes on different threads via the signal / slot system. The receiving Objects are created in a Function which is run via std::async.
The problem is: If the widget emits a signal the slot on the other thread is not called.

My Example:

I created the Class MainWindow which derives from QMainWindow and will live on the main thread. The class Reciever is created in a function which is called via std::async, and has a thread which should print something to the console.

I tested if the signal is emitted by connecting it to another slot on the same thread which works fine.

**MainWindow.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
     explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:
    void send();

private slots:
    void buttonClicked();
    void recieve();
};
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.hpp"
#include <iostream>

#include <QPushButton>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QPushButton* start = new QPushButton("Start");
    setCentralWidget(start);
    start->show();

    connect(start, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(buttonClicked()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(send()), this, SLOT(recieve()));
}

void MainWindow::buttonClicked()
{
    std::cout << "MainWindow::buttonClicked()\n";
    emit send();
}

void MainWindow::recieve()
{
    std::cout << "MainWindow::recieve()\n";
}
```

**Reciever.hpp**

```
#include <QObject>

class Reciever : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Reciever(QObject *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void recieve();
};
```

**Reciever.cpp**

```
#include "Reciever.hpp"

#include <iostream>

Reciever::Reciever(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    std::cout << "Reciever()" << std::endl;
}

void Reciever::recieve()
{
    std::cout << "Reciever::recieve()" << std::endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.hpp"
#include "Reciever.hpp"
#include <QApplication>

#include <future>

void StartAndConnect(MainWindow &widget)
{
    Reciever* rec = new Reciever();

    QObject::connect(&widget, SIGNAL(send()), rec, SLOT(recieve()));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow myWidget;

    myWidget.show();

    auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, [&myWidget](){
        StartAndConnect(myWidget);
    });

    app.exec();

    future.wait();
}
```

After some research my strongest guess was, that the thread launched by std::async does not has a Qt event-loop and thus will not come to a point where the posted event (emit) is processed. I changed the main to use QtConcurrent::run but it also did not work.

**EDIT**

Here my try with QtConcurrent:

**main2.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.hpp"
#include "Reciever.hpp"
#include <QApplication>

#include <future>
#include <QtConcurrent>

void StartAndConnect(MainWindow &widget)
{
    Reciever* rec = new Reciever();

    QObject::connect(&widget, SIGNAL(send()), rec, SLOT(recieve()));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow myWidget;

    myWidget.show();

    auto future = QtConcurrent::run( [&myWidget](){
    StartAndConnect(myWidget);
    });

    app.exec();

    future.waitForFinished();
}
```

Comment: You certainly need the event loop. Can you post the code instead where you tried to have an event loop?

Comment: I added the changed main as main2.cpp

Comment: You still don't have an event loop in your thread. Why you simply don't use `QThread`?

Comment: Because I started with std::async and modified my code from that point. I also thought QtConcurrent would use QThread and would therefor be equivalent.

Comment: @ab.o2c 1) Why do you think that `QtConcurrent` will start an event loop for you? 2) Why you don't use `QThread` if you mandatory need an event loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a running event loop in your thread, if you want to process cross-thread slot calls.

```
auto future = QtConcurrent::run( [&myWidget](){
StartAndConnect(myWidget);
QEventLoop e;
e.exec();
});
```

But I recomend to use `QThread`, because in your case it is obvious. Qt has a [very good documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details), that describes your case.